# Pivot Table VBA is coming up empty

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am learning VBA and trying to insert a pivot table on a worksheet. I have written the code for it and the pivot table is being created and renamed but the only trouble i am getting is my pivot table is coming empty. My worksheet name us names Report.

My code below also shows that i inserted Column fields, Row Fields and data fields. Something wrong with cache or how I am inserting my values?. This pivot table doesn't produce any errors. Let me know if you have any tips. Thanks

```
Sub InsertPivotTable()

'Declare Variables
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

'Insert a New Blank Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set PSheet = Worksheets("Summary")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("Report")

'Define Data Range
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
TableName:="SalesPivotTable")

'Insert Blank Pivot Table
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="SalesPivotTable")

'Insert Row Fields
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesPivotTable").PivotFields("Works For Code")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesPivotTable").PivotFields("Category Name")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 2
End With

'Insert Column Fields
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesPivotTable").PivotFields("GL Account")
.Orientation = xlColumnField
.Position = 1
End With

'Insert Data Field
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesPivotTable").PivotFields("Expense Amount")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Function = xlSum
.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
.Name = "Revenue "
End With

'Format Pivot Table
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesPivotTable").ShowTableStyleRowStripes = True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesPivotTable").TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium9"

End Sub
```

Comment: Comment out `On Error Resume Next` and report back on the line that throws an error and the error message.

Comment: @BigBen Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete

Comment: Get rid of `. _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
TableName:="SalesPivotTable")`

Comment: @BigBen Set PSheet = Worksheets("Summary"). That's strange

Comment: @BigBen It's working. Thanks